# Use Async Task in oncreateview

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, oncreate, fragment-oncreateview

Is there a way to overwrite the "week_kg" variable with the async task in the `oncreateview` method? 
The async task overwrites the variable, but the View is already created and doesn't contain the new value.

It's a Rest Communications with a Node.js Server and a Mysql database.

```
public class Feedback extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecylcerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


    public String username = "ilovenature";

    public double week_kg;

    String resturl = "http://192.168.178.199:3000/"; //ip


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feedback, container, false);

        new HttpGet().execute(resturl + "user/" + username);

        ArrayList < Feedback_inhalt > feedback_inhalt = new ArrayList<>();
        feedback_inhalt.add(new Feedback_inhalt(R.mipmap.ic_plastic_color, "Verwertungskosten", "kg eingespart", week_kg));


        mRecylcerView = view.findViewById(R.id.feedback_view);
        mRecylcerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        mAdapter = new FeedbackAdapter(feedback_inhalt);

        mRecylcerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecylcerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }


    public class HttpGet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...strURLs) {
            URL url;
            String output;
            HttpURLConnection conn;
            try {
                url = new URL(strURLs[0]);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(output);
                }
                return sb.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                week_kg = jsonObject.getDouble("wochenkilogramm");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onCreateView()` method is only called once when the view is created.

However, you can refresh your `RecyclerView` once your `AsyncTask` has finished executing. To achieve this, add the newly fetched data to your `ArrayList feedback_halt` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.

When you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the views will be refreshed based on the data in your ArrayList.

So, inside `onPostExecute()` after you have set the value of `week_kg`:

```
feedback_inhalt.add(new Feedback_inhalt(R.mipmap.ic_plastic_color, "Verwertungskosten", "kg eingespart", week_kg));
mAdapter.notifyDatSetChanged()
```

Finally, the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method should only be called from a UI thread but the `onPostExecute()` method runs on the UI thread by design so you are good to go :-)